# display inline-block in css menu

Tags: css, menu, menubar

I'm trying to make my website's menu elements next to each other with the display: inline-block. I've tried it in different parts of my CSS menu, like at the 'cssmenu li' etc, but it doesn't work. Somebody knows how to help me?

**The CSS:**

```css
#cssmenu {
    border: none;
    border: 0px;
    margin: -17px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: none;
    float: left;
    width: 600;
    margin-left: 300px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
}
#cssmenu ul {
    background: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}
#cssmenu li a {
    background: #fff url('seperator.png') bottom right no-repeat;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #000;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
    color: #000;
}
#cssmenu li > a:hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a {
    background: #fff url('hover.png') bottom center no-repeat;
    color: #ddd;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu li ul {
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 225px;
    z-index: 200;
    /*top:1em;*/
    /*left:0px;*/
}
#cssmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu li li {
    background: url('sub_sep.png') bottom left no-repeat;
    float: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 225px;
    background: #hhh url('hover_sub.png') center left no-repeat;
    border: 0px;
    color: #000;
}
#cssmenu li:hover li a {
    background: none;
    color: #000;
    font: "Times New Roman", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu li ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu li ul a:hover,
#cssmenu li ul li:hover > a {
    background: #fff url('hover_sub.png') center left no-repeat;
    border: 0px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu p {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some test html, possibly at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to make it possible to test out the errors?

Comment: Remove you `margin-left`? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWcLp/1/)

Comment: I need the margin-left and removing it doesn't help either. I'm not common with JSFiddle and can't seem to get it the way it is on my website now: http://jsfiddle.net/d9Srw/. You might want to check it on my website: http://taoofsophia.blogandthecity.net

Comment: comment out the white space in between your elements if you are using inline-block

Comment: what do you mean with 'comment out the white space'?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with #cssmenu li {display: inline block;} and #cssmenu li a {padding: 0 16px;} but your html is wrong. Check your ul's and li's again. You need:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub">
            <a></a>
            ...
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub">
            <a></a>
            ...
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub">
            <a></a>
            ...
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Even I can see that. UL is generating again and again! Looks like he is using some kind of loop to generate that result

Comment: Yes, if you view page source you can notice some code before doctype, I believe that is making this mess.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've corrected the html code now! But the display: inline-block still doesn't seems to work. Somebody wants to check what I've did? Really appreciate it!

Comment: Never mind, I will remove the CSS menu. Actually don't really need it :)

Comment: Whatever you want but you just need to decrease padding on <a> to 16px like I said and to remove float left on <li>.